# How to install virtual machine?

Tags: virtual-machine, distributed-computing

I am working on a project on distributed systems using MPI (Message Passing Interface). I need multiple systems for the simulation but I have only one system. How can I install a virtual machine on my system which will serve the purpose?
Operating System: Ubuntu 15.04

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about the multiple machines but you could use the VMWar or virtual Box , or else there is a functionality that allows two systems on single machine

Answer (score 0):

You can use Virtual box to run multiple OS at a time.

Please refer my blog for more info:

http://trainenv.blogspot.in/2016/03/creating-virtual-machine-in-virtual-box.html